# invalid type for key expires_on, expected date, but got string php

Tags: php, date, parse-platform

I am facing a problem that whenever I try to store date in parse it gives me this error 'invalid type for key expires_on, expected date, but got string'. How can I convert string object to date object? The format of date '21 April 2015 - 10:50' and the data type of column field in Parse DB is date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime` function of PHP to store data if your getting it into string.

```
$input_date = $_REQUEST['expireDate'];

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i',$input_date);

$expireDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');

echo $expireDate;
```

The above code will convert your string into date that will be used to store data

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is not working, still it gives me string datatype.

Comment: What you are getting within string can you update your question. What I have done over here is I have converted your `'21 April 2015 - 10:50' ` as date. I thought you might be getting your values within this format in string

Comment: Well i actually get date from calendar and submit it through form, then i get that value of input field from $_REQUEST. so after that when i store that value in table then it gives me error.

Comment: Thats because you are getting string value and storing directly into your `db` Have you tried the above code

Comment: yes i have tried your code, infact i simple copy paste that code with static date value, but when i get the type from gettype function it is also giving me string type.

Comment: Can you please update your question what you were getting within `$_REQUEST[]`

Comment: $expireDate= $_REQUEST['expireDate'];
i am getting date from input field like this and then i want to store $expireDate variable in database.

Comment: @Subzz I have updated answer you can check it..

Comment: Thanks Man. but is not working :( 
actually when you use gettype($expireDate) function to get the datatype of $expireDate it gives me string instead of date.. Thats my point.

Comment: But you can store that value within database are you getting any error within it while storing within database